# How to statically add an image in django

Tags: django

Any one could help to add an image on the following view function, I tried adding the following way

```
 Category.objects.create(
            name='Others',
            slug='others',
            image='home/xxx/xx/static/assets/images/xxx.png'
        )
```

also tried

```
Category.objects.create(
            name='Others',
            slug='others',
            image=static('home/xxx/xx/static/assets/images/xxx.png')
        )
```

image is not getting saved in both the ways

Comment: Install [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) python package for image upload.

Comment: pillow is installed already